# How can I insert my class objects into my non-STL List?

Tags: c++, list

I have been working on this assignment for a while now and am quite stuck with inserting into my non-STL list. The code will compile successfully, but segfaults every time it goes to insert into my list. Below is some relevant code.

**tripper.h:**

```
class adjNode
{
  public:
    int vertex;
    int weight;
    adjNode(int v, int w) : vertex(v), weight(w) { }
    adjNode() { }
};
```

**tripper.cpp:**

```
Tripper::Tripper(Road *roads, int numRoads, int size)
{
  List <adjNode> adjList[numRoads];

  for (int i=0; i<numRoads; i++) //Doesn't work with either line
  {
    adjList[roads[i].city1].push_back(adjNode(roads[i].city2, roads[i].distance));
    //adjList[0].push_back(adjNode(2, 15)); //Really it's nothing but 3 integers involved
  }
  for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
  {
    for (List<adjNode>::iterator itr = adjList[i].begin(); itr != adjList[i].end(); itr++)
    {
      cout << "There is an edge going from " << i << " to " << (*itr).vertex;
      cout << " with a weight of " << (*itr).weight << endl;
    }
  }
} // Tripper()
```

**list.h:**

```
void push_back( const Object & x )
{ 
  insert( end( ), x ); 
}
iterator insert( iterator itr, const Object & x )
{
    Node *p = itr.current;
    theSize++;
    return iterator( p->prev = p->prev->next = new Node( x, p->prev, p ) );
}
```

Node

```
 struct Node { 
   Object data; 
   Node *prev; 
   Node *next; 
   Node( const Object & d = Object( ), Node * p = NULL, Node * n = NULL ) 
        : data( d ), prev( p ), next( n ) 
   {
   } 
 };
```

Comment: You're getting segfaults, and nowhere in that code do I see evidence of memory allocation. I'm guessing there's a connection.

Comment: in first for loop add 'assert (roads[i].city1 < numRoads);' and anyway - why making array the size of roads and access it with cities iterator?

Answer (score 1):

return iterator( p->prev = p->prev->next = new Node( x, p->prev, p ) );

This line will crash if p->prev is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Use pen and paper and draw arrows for your pointer ops.

Separate the ops on different lines to be able to express your intent and debug the code more easily.

Comment: The only real problem is with the line: "adjList[0].push_back(adjNode(2, 15));"

I know it creates the adjNode successfully as I can reference the data in a cout statement. I am more or less puzzled (or missing something) in terms of the creation of my list (can I use the [numRoads] after it?) and, as the other user mentioned, I don't thinK I am allocating memory.

Comment: What does the `Node` constructor look like? If it doesn't somehow make a copy of `x`, you'll crash as soon as the `adjNode` goes out of scope.

Comment: struct Node
    {
        Object  data;
        Node   *prev;
        Node   *next;

        Node( const Object & d = Object( ), Node * p = NULL, Node * n = NULL )
          : data( d ), prev( p ), next( n ) { }
    };

Comment: @Brian what is the head of the list initialised to? If Node.prev defaults to null, and you haven't done anything else to the head of the list, the first time you insert p->prev will be null and you get UB when you set p->prev->next

Comment: @Pete: It would seem as though it is not initialized to anything. How would I properly go about declaring that I want to have a list that contains adjList objects that I can reference? I am doing this with the hopes that I can use this adjacency list for my Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Oh, and as it is surely relevant, I am implementing this with some modifications for my purposes: http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Graph_data_structures#Adjacency_List